# Laravel Replace Unicode Characters in Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I stored some hours from Google Places and little did I know it brought in some longer dashes (\u2013) and I'd like to loop through and convert anything in the database that is a unicode string into a normal string, as when I retrieve these hours I can't explode them via

```
explode(' - ', $hours);
```

What's the best way to do this in Laravel/MySQL/PHP?

Comment: Have you tried [preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split)? I guess you can do something like `preg_split('/\x{2013}/u', $hours);`, considering that `2013` is a hex value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an SQL query for that:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `column`=REPLACE(`column`, '–', '-')
```

Comment: Thanks! This did it for me without replacing other bad things